# How to do a Web Server in NodeJs that makes a REST call to API REST?

Tags: node.js, rest, api

I researched a lot, but I cannot find a solution.

I have to do a Web Server in Nodejs and, until here, ok... but how to make a REST call? Do I have to use express or not? I just don't understand. I find so many things and I don't know how to use them.
I have to do the REST call to an API REST.

For example: my web server starts (on local host) and it allows to share something on facebook.

But I don't even know where to put the API code.

Thanks!
P.s. i'm not english so i can't express myself very well

This is the web server code:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.end('Web Server');
})

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

I know it's very easy but I just don't get it...

To specify, the **assignment** is "implement a nodejs server that is able to make a REST call to any one of the REST API offers in http://www.programmableweb.com/ and displays the result".

Comment: You question is innocent , don't worry its easy stuff . Can you upload your sample server code

Comment: Just Read this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm

Comment: The question suggests you don't know what REST or API means.

Comment: @Sumeet I've already read it (so many times!), i'm following that tutorial, but i haven't find a solution... thanks anyway!

Comment: @Sumeet I uploaded the code :)

Comment: Ok .. give me a moment I am writing small rest call for you in your example @Sara

Comment: @OrangeDog this is surely a reason: i don't understand where i am, it's a new field for me. plus, i'm not english so i used wrong words etc. I know what is an API, and I know what is the purpose of REST, but I didn't understand very well how to use it. How to take what I need from APIs (and WHAT i need?) and where e and how to put them in my code...

Comment: This might be a starting point? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model

Comment: @OrangeDog thank you!

Comment: Check this blog also http://bigspaceship.github.io/blog/2014/05/14/how-to-create-a-rest-api-with-node-dot-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest api can be developed using only node native library . In below example i have user url api to develop that

```
var http = require('http');
var url  = require('url');


var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var path = url.parse(req.url, true);
    console.log(path.pathname);
    if(path.pathname == '/customer'){
        // Send some Customer Data 

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
            customerName : 'abc',
            purchase : 200,
            deliverDate : new Date()
        }));
    }else if(path.pathname == '/vendor'){
        // Send some Customer Data 

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
            vendorName : 'abc',
            price : 1000,
            orderDate : new Date()
        }));

    }else{
        res.end('Wrong Path !!! - API not Found ');
    }


})

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

There are  other ways also , like using express middle ware to avoid url parsing manually .

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    app.get('/customer', function(req, res) {
      res.send({
            customerName : 'abc',
            purchase : 200,
            deliverDate : new Date()
        });
    });
   app.get('/vendor', function(req, res) {
      res.send({
            vendorName : 'abc',
            price : 1000,
            orderDate : new Date()
        });
    });
    app.listen(1337);
    console.log('Listening on port 1337...');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try to do something with this code! :D

Comment: Welcome to stack over flow , #keepusing